# JavaScript to execute a function after certain events have occurred?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, event-handling, dom-events

I apologize if this question has been asked before, I've tried searching and don't think I'm hitting the right phrasing.

I have two files loading in via AJAX and I don't want to execute a function until both of them are loaded.

I'm trying to have a function execute after certain events have happened. The pseudo for what I'm thinking of doing is as such:

```
onEvent(A or B){
    if( eventA.has_occurred AND eventB.has_occurred ){
        do X;
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how I would implement the above *elegantly*. I know how to make the above with a horrible hack but not how to do it well. Further, if there is a better way to trigger a function after multiple file loads please let me know.

Comment: You're looking to use something called promises.
Check out q: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Also take a look at how jQuery implements a success callback for ajax http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/

Comment: And what does the actual code you're using for ajax look like ?

Comment: Can you describe the "horrible hack" shortly, just to prevent people to waste their time by using the same hack in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with two events, you could do something like this (it's a little cumbersome, but I think it's a nice way to do it...run the snippet to see it work):

```js
// Custom Events
var e1 = new Event('event1');
var e2 = new Event('event2');
// Dispatching Wrappers
var callE1 = function(){ document.getElementById("txt").dispatchEvent(e1); };
var callE2 = function(){ document.getElementById("txt").dispatchEvent(e2); };
// Called by whenDone()
var updateText = function(elt){
    elt.innerHTML = "Done!";
};
// Called after both events
var whenDone = function(e){ 
    // (the text resetting for the second event gets overwritten
    //  by the first one...see below)
    document.getElementById("e1txt").innerHTML = "Done!";
    document.getElementById("e2txt").innerHTML = "Done!";
    updateText(e.target); };
// NOTE: e2 listener (not a typo)
var updateE1 = function(e){
    // Mark e2 as done
    document.getElementById("e2txt").innerHTML = "Done!";
    // Remove the default e1 listener
    e.target.removeEventListener('event1', updateE2);
    // Replace it with a new listener which contains
    //  whatever is to be done after both events
    e.target.addEventListener('event1',whenDone);
};
// NOTE: e1 listener
var updateE2 = function(e){
    // Mark e1 as done
    document.getElementById("e1txt").innerHTML = "Done!";
    // Remove the default e2 listener
    e.target.removeEventListener('event2', updateE1);
    // Replace it with a new listener which contains
    //  whatever is to be done after both events
    e.target.addEventListener('event2',whenDone);
};

// Resets the page... purely for demo purposes
var reset = function(){
    document.getElementById("e1txt").innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    document.getElementById("e2txt").innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Waiting...";
    document.getElementById("txt").removeEventListener('event1', whenDone);
    document.getElementById("txt").removeEventListener('event2', whenDone);
    document.getElementById("txt").removeEventListener('event1', updateE2);
    document.getElementById("txt").removeEventListener('event2', updateE1);
    document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener('event1', updateE2);
    document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener('event2', updateE1);
    // Call events at some random time after up to 10 seconds
    setTimeout(callE1, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * 1000);
    setTimeout(callE2, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * 1000);
};
// Reset every 12 seconds
reset();
setInterval(function(){reset();}, 12000);
```

```html
(Note: This snippet resets every 12 Seconds)<br/>
Event 1: <div id="e1txt">Waiting...</div><br/>
Event 2: <div id="e2txt">Waiting...</div><br/>
Both:<div id="txt">Waiting...</div>
```

If you need *more* events, then things get a little tricky. You could either have the event invocations toggle some member of a list of state booleans or you could branch this method somehow.